# Building React Native App for Release to Store

Tags: react-native, tfs, continuous-integration

I am building out a CI build script to prepare a React Native application for the App/Play store. Looking at [the official docs][1], there are several manual steps involved that must be done each time. Obviously, I'm shooting for a hands-off build process.

Is there an automatic way of generating a signed and ready for upload iOS/Android build that I'm missing?

Comment: You are lacking of the link in your question, according to your TFS tag, did you mean you are using TFS to do the CI build process?

Answer (score 0):

For Android - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html - that works all from CI.

For iOS I'm not sure, I always need to use XCode - https://www.raywenderlich.com/127939/submit-an-app-part-2 - I do hear though that Expo gives you a IPA file and that can be uploaded, but never sure.

Comment: The Android CI process has never worked for me, I've always had to do it through Android Studio.

Comment: @MattyK14 where does it fail? You might need to `cd android` `./gradlew clean` first. I need to do this pretty often.